# Manage over 10000 annotations on MapKit view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit

do you have some strategy for manage over 10000 annotations on a small area inside a MapKit view... I have set a filter for manage that when the user change the zoom level but with over 10000 iterations it's very slow....

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What is usually done is merge several annotations that are close to each other into only one and show them in more detail once the user zooms in. Would that work for you?

Comment: do you have an easy way to do that

Comment: Well, Do you? :) I'm looking for this answer also

Comment: http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/revmapcluster or http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ocmapview will work